# C++ CLI nested default index

Tags: c++-cli

I have a class that contains a list of objects, for which there is a default index property. Each object has a list for which i want to create another default index.

```
    public ref class Foo
    {
    //List of Bars
    public:
        property Bar^ default[int]; //Returns a Bar
    }

    public ref class Bar
    {
    //List of things
    public:
        property Thing^ default[int]; //Returns a Thing
    }
```

Instead of calling it with...

```
    Foo.Bars[i].Things[k]
```

...i want to do something like...

```
    Foo[i][k]
```

...to get my thing.

It is telling me that...

> The function Foo::default[int]::get cannot be called with the given argument list
>
> Argument types are get(int, int).

...as if i am trying to call get(int, int) but that is not my intention.

What does seem to be working is if i have another default index in Foo that is two dimentional, where the second dimention returns the Thing from the Bar, but i was hoping to have an implementation where Thing is not accessible from Foo.

Your guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: Hard to guess what you did, smells like you tried to make Foo[i, k] work.  It has to be Foo[i][k], as written.

Comment: That is correct. Foo[i][k] and Foo[i,k] worked since i added a multidimentional default indexer, as a test. I need it to test the first bracket pair and index the **result** with the second pair, it is considering them to be 2 indexers on the same object. Might there be a decorator to force this behavior?

Comment: Focus on showing us correct repro code.

Comment: @xanatos code below is a perfect example for reproduction of the issue. Please try it, and if it works for you too, then the problem is definitely on my side.

Comment: @HansPassant I've a "funny" problem where the code I gave Bagaboo as the solution runs correctly but the editor (VS2017) marks the use of the indexer as an error (the Intellisense gives a E1767 error). I'm doing it on a "new" clean console C++/CLI project.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense.  The IntelliSense parser is made by a different company (EDG), it does have compatibility problems.  No simple ways to bypass them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
public ref class Thing
{

};

public ref class Bar
{
    //List of things
public:
    property Thing^ default[int]
    {
        Thing^ get(int index)
        {
            return gcnew Thing();
        }
    }//Returns a Thing
};

public ref class Foo
{
    //List of 
public:
    property Bar^ default[int]
    {
        Bar^ get(int index)
        {
            return gcnew Bar();
        }
    }
};
```

and then

```
Foo^ test = gcnew Foo();
Thing^ res = test[5][3];
```

compiles correctly. You probably didn't include the `get` part, or you put the `Foo` class before the `Bar` class.

Comment: Strange. I did the exact same test in a new project and got the same error. It is as if it is considering test[5][3] as test::get(5,3). Might we have different configurations somehow? What configuration could that be in that case?

Comment: @Bagaboo I'm using VS 2017... I've noticed that the editor marks `test[5][3]` as wrong with the error you gave, but the compiler compiles it correctly and if I run the code with F5 the code runs correctly

Comment: Good. That means we have the exact same "issue" since it works when i just run it but intellisense is showing an error still. I will troubleshoot that instead. Thank you!